# How to select inputs elements in divs which not hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, select

How can I select an array of `input` and `select` elements that are not hidden from the form below, using jQuery?

```
  <form class="FORM_1">
    <div class="a" style="display:inline-block><input id="A"/></div>

    <div class="a" style="display:none"><input id="B"/></div>

    <div class="a"><select id="C"/></div>
    <div class="a"style="display:none"><select id="D"/></div>

    <div class="a style="display:inline-block"><input id="F"/></div>
   </form>
```

I tried with code below but it doesn't work how I need.

```
$('.FORM_1 input, .FORM_1 select').prop('display', 'inline-block').each(function(index){  
  var input = $(this);      
  console.log('Type: ' + input.attr('type'));
});
```

Comment: Use the `:visible` selector: `$('.FORM_1 input:visible, .FORM_1 select:visible')`

Comment: Apart from that, please take a look at your html . There are a bunch of errors in there :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `is(":visible")` to select visible elements

```
$('.FORM_1 input:visible, .FORM_1 select:visible').addClass('YourStuff');
```

Below code is enough to display the elements, If you want display inline block, assign in css first as inline block and add display none as inline like below

```
input, select {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Then in html

```
<input style="display: none;" />
```

Then in JS

```
$('.FORM_1 input, .FORM_1 select').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".FORM_1 input:visible, .FORM_1 select:visible").each(function(index) {
  var input = $(this);
  console.log("Type: " + input.prop("type"));
});
```

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="FORM_1">
  <div class="a"><input id="A" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="a" style="display:none"><input id="B" type="text" /></div>

  <div class="a"><select id="C"></select></div>
  <div class="a" style="display:none"><select id="D"></select></div>

  <div class="a"><input id="F" type="text" /></div>
</form>
```